# Laravel 5: How to use Regular Expression Parameter Constraints with utf-8 strings?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

does anyone know how to use Regular Expression Parameter Constraints with utf-8 strings?

This one works with US-ASCII (Basic Latin) script: www.domain.com/test

```
Route::get('{slug}', function($slug) { dd($slug); })->where('slug', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

but it doesn't work with any other non US-ASCII script: www.domain.com/тест

```
Route::get('{slug}', function($slug) { dd($slug); })->where('slug', '/\p{L}+/u');
```

I think that Laravel does support only simplified regexes in route patterns so anything in the form of "/^(regex)$/u" is stripped leaving only the simple (regex).

I've also tried defining a global pattern with custom 'regex:' but that dosn't work either.